# SublimeText3 Bookmark

Tags: sublimetext3, bookmarks

I'm using SublimeText3 and have a few questions around managing bookmarks.  I tried better bookmarks but the only problem is that when you close the file the bookmarks are cleared and when you close and reopen ST3 its all gone.  I want to preserve the bookmarks when you close files/ST3.  Is there any package that can support this?

I also tried sublimebookmarks and the same problem, when I close the file I loosed the bookmarks.

Answer (score 0):

I got sublime bookmarks working based on the following link.

https://github.com/bollu/sublimeBookmark/issues/23

Basically you need to modify the sublimebookmark.py file and its all good.  I tested it as well.  The bookmarks take a bit of time to load but apart from that its all good.